# How do you correctly encode JSON from MYSQL, ready for Highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

I am trying to do what i think to be a fairly simple task, but I'm having a nightmare doing it.
I want a Highcharts bar/spline chart generated from mysql results.
I have produced many Highcharts that are based on single results, but Im struggling with a populating an entire series from a results column.

Starting off, I have a mysql view containing 4 fields. key, date, pos, and rating

```
Example Data
Key             date          pos          rating
1026         2013-06-22        7            77.5
1021         2013-05-16        9            65.4
1019         2013-04-21        4            82.5
1002         2013-03-12        5            81.4
```

I am trying to get the date on the x axis, pos as a bar series, and rating as a spline series. 
After looking into why I cannot get the chart to show, I find that I need to prepare the data using JSON before hand. This is where I'm totally lost...
I have never used JSON before and cant find any simple examples that I can follow using mysql, so could someone please help. I'm sure it's only about 10lines of code that's doing my nut in :)

The query I am trying to use is...

```
$sql = "SELECT key, date, pos, rating FROM results WHERE key=146";
```

I think i have echoed a JSON using this

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT key, date, pos, rating FROM results WHERE key=146";   
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
$json['JSON_info'][]=$row;
}
}
mysql_close($worstat);
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

This gave me the following output which I thought was close to what I needed, but further reading told me that I need to remove all the speech marks...

```
{"JSON_info":[["146","2013-06-23","7","66.15"],["146","2013-06-09","4","77.12"],
["146","2013-05-05","6","81.95"],["146","2013-04-07","11","77.15"],["146","2012-12-
30","6","58.17"],["146","2012-12-09","5","42.58"],["146","2012-10-07","7","74.66"],["146","2012-
09-16","18","78.86"],["146","2012-09-16","17","79.87"],["146","2012-09-16","15","80.23"],
["146","2012-09-16","20","72.32"],["146","2012-08-12","9","57.58"],["146","2012-07-
01","19","80.09"],["146","2012-06-03","7","51.64"],["146","2012-06-02","8","81.37"],["146","2012-
04-01","10","80.66"],["146","2012-02-05","9","64.08"]]}
```

Looking at the demo chart at Highcharts, I see the chart requires the data like so...

```
series: [{
name: 'Rainfall',
color: '#4572A7',
type: 'column',
yAxis: 1,
data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
tooltip: {
valueSuffix: ' mm'
}
```

Before I get lost going in a totally wrong direction could someone give me some pointers.

1. How do I strip the speech marks?
2. How do I then remove the unwanted key field that was used for the results filtering?
3. How do I assign it to the chart series?

Not that it will help, but my example page is at: http://www.kr3w.co.uk/WORStat_2/profile.php?TargetName=146 its the 5th chart down that's not playing ball

Comment: show the format needed to plot  the chart

Comment: I'm assuming you're having problems with quotations because highcharts treat the numbers as strings, according to your JSON. If you can confirm that's the problem, it would be a step forward.

Comment: I edited in a snippet from the chart example.

Comment: So which key from the snippet do you require? The `data` one?

Comment: N.B: from what other have told me I think that is the problem yes. I cannot be sure though because I have never used this method before to output a chart.

Comment: What are "speech marks"?

Comment: N.B: I require `date`, `pos` and `rating`. The chart will not require `key` it was just used to filter the results set out. I'm assuming I have to remove `key` before sending to the chart?

Comment: The problem is that if you quote something (quotes = what you called speech marks), that means it is treated as string. Highcharts require a **number**. What you need to do is type-cast the data MySQL gives you. I can post an example if you wish, you can try to adjust it.

Comment: Your table doesn't have a column named `riderkey`, but you're referencing that column in your PHP, could that be the issue?

Comment: If you have an example i can try N.B. , that my be helpful.

Comment: Arunu: sry about that, that was a typo.

Comment: Arunu, the demo chart I am attempting to mirror is http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the issue boils down to not sending correct data-types. Also, you're using an obsolete `mysql_*` extension, you should consider using PDO.

The line that creates issue is this one:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $json['JSON_info'][]=$row;
}
```

What it should be is:

```
$json['JSON_info'][] = array(
    (int)$row['Key'],
    $row['date'],
    (int)$row['pos'],
    (float)$row['rating']
);
```

That will make `json_encode` to properly quote (or not quote) the values.

Comment: I now see how your pulling them in from mysql along with the units  type, but when I `echo json_encode($json);` I now just get the response `{"JSON_info":[[0,null,0,0]]}`. Should I be echoing another way to see the full array, or should I just start pulling my hair out now and be done with it hehe :)

Comment: I had a typo there, and you copy-pasted the example (which is always a bad idea). Instead of `$result` it should be `$row`. I'll edit it but bear in mind - never copy-paste because we're all humans :)

Comment: no problem, I wouldn't of spotted that sry :)
`echo json_encode($json);` still gives me the same response `{"JSON_info":[[0,null,0,0]]}`

Answer (score 0):

though i hope you've figured this out by now, the fella above is mostly correct, but he neglected to mention that you need to change

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
```

to

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

so the final code is

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $json['JSON_info'][] = array(
    (int)$row['Key'],
    $row['date'],
    (int)$row['pos'],
    (float)$row['rating']
);
```